# Possible to show 'Request new password' tab with LoginToboggan 403 login page?

Tags: 7

I'm using the LoginToboggan module to password protect a page.  A login area successfully shows on the page in question, but there are no tabs, only a username and password box.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what the I want it to look like (screenshot taken from /user on same site):

[image]

I can't see any option for it in the configuration (here is what I have currently as config under the login section):

[image]

I can't find anything relating to this in the LoginToboggan issue queue or via google.  Has anyone experienced this? Is there any way I can make the tabs display?

P.s. I was going to log a support request on the issue queue of LoginToboggan but I saw the following statement:

```
Support requests will only be responded to if they deal with the development of the
module, or possibly its use with another module. End users should consult the forums or
IRC chat rooms or hire a consultant for support.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a page is forbidden, logintoboggan pulls the login form via the following code:

```
drupal_get_form('user_login');
```

For some reason, which I haven't figured out, calling `user_login` doesn't include the links to 'reset password' and 'create new account'.  I've submitted a patch to the module, which adds an option in the configuration to include the 'forgot password' and 'create account' links.  It uses `user_login_block` instead of 'user_login' to render the form with the 'forgot password' and 'create account' links.

Here is a screenshot of the admin area:

[image: Login Toboggan Settings]

Here is a link to the issue that contains the patch: [Add lost password link to 403 login form](http://drupal.org/node/1823764)

Edit: I think the reason that the tabs for 'Request new password' and 'Create new account' aren't displayed, is that they are MENU_LOCAL_TASK's on the 'user' page.  Logintoboggan redirects to 'toboggan/denied', so the tabs aren't being pulled in.

Answer (score 1):

That page is controlled by a theme function theme_lt_unified_login_page() and theme functions can be overridden. That's probably how I would do it.

Comment: Awesome!  I'll have a go at overriding it.

Comment: When a page is forbidden (403), logintoboggan seems to use user_login rather than theme_lt_unified_login_page to display the login form.